# How to println list of object in wicket table?

Tags: java, wicket

I have class:

```
public class PlayerResult implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long playerResultId;

    private Player player;

    private String score;

    private List<Result> results;
...
}
```

How I can print this class into wicket table ? First column should be player name and surname then result.size() columns of result.toString() and last columns should be score

thx for help

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would use DataTable or AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable.

Comment: I follow this example: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.AjaxDataTablePage?0 but I have no idea how to pass list of class into columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

Sorry I didn't undertand the question the first time.

I have never tried this (so not sure if it possible)  but perhaps you could also apply a ListView to the `<td>` tags (for the Results) like it is done in the `<tr>` tags (for the PlayerResults).

Java:

```
List<PlayerResult> players = // ...
ListModel<PlayerResult> playersModel = new ListModel<PlayerResult>(players);
ListView<PlayerResult> list = new ListView<PlayerResult>("list", playersModel) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<PlayerResult> item) {
        Label name = new Label("name", new PropertyModel<String>(item.getModel(), "player.name"));
        Label surname = new Label("surname", new PropertyModel<String>(item.getModel(), "player.surname"));
        Label results= new Label("results", item.getModelObject().getResults().size());

        ListView<Result> scoreList= new ListView<Result>("scoreList", item.getModelObject().getResults()){
             @Override
             protected void populateItem(ListItem<Result> resultItem) {
                   item.add(new Label("score", new PropertyModel<Integer>(resultItem.getModel(), "scoreValue ? ")));
             }
        }

        // ...

        item.add(name);
        item.add(surname);
        item.add(results);
        item.add(scoreList);
        // ...
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr wicket:id="list">
        <td><span wicket:id="name">[name label]</span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="surname">[surname label]</span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="results">[results label]</span></td>
        <!-- and now variable number of tds -->
        <td wicket:id="scoreList">
             <span wicket:id="score"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: eh you are sure ? this code isnt compiled. There isnt such constructor: new Label("results", item.getModelObject().getResults().size()); new Label(String, int) ...

Comment: Yes you need to use a string or a model (that is trivial). Code was not tested. No need to -1 for that

Comment: yes because you didnt understand my question and your example doesnt make any sence. You just add ONE column where will be value size of result but I want add to table x column where x is size of result list so ur question is totally off = -1

Answer (score 2):

Do all players' result list have the same size?
Then just implement a IDataProvider iterating over your PlayerResults.

Add appropriate columns:

new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Name"). "player.name");

new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Surame"). "player.surname");

new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Result 1"). "results.0");

new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Result 2"). "results.1");
...

Sven

Comment: hm and do you try this ? Because "results.0" throw me exception: No get method defined for class: class org.toursys.repository.model.PlayerResult expression: results and I have there such method

Comment: seems you forgot to define setters and getters